# How can I send to both Google Logger and cout?

Tags: c++, c++11, logging, glog

I'm using the google logger (glog) in a C++ project, where source code contains printout of informational items and progress:

```
std::cout << some_useful_stuff << "\n";
```

And I can use GLOG to log informational items:

```
LOG(INFO) << some_useful_stuff << "\n"; \\ gets echoed to stdout
```

I can't change all the `std::cout` statements throughout the codebase (as I'm using some subrepos from third parties etc, and *unable to add my own logging statements to them*), this prevents me from using an if-else construct (which would be ugly anyway, wrapping every single output statement in logic).

So how could I replicate `stdout` outputs to GLog?

```
std::cout << some_useful_stuff << "\n"; \\ message also goes to LOG(INFO)
```

Possibly useful: I actually don't need this to happen at the same time; it's useful to have a choice like {CONSOLE, LOGS, BOTH} but I could put up with the simpler choice between {CONSOLE, LOGS}.

Also - experienced programmer but C++ newbie so if this is mega simple; apologies - and thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for edit, @Borgleader... beat me to that change ;)

Comment: [boost::iostreams::tee_device](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iostreams/doc/functions/tee.html) are useful for writing to two streams simultaneously. Basically a wrapper for two streams.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about glog, but usually we use dup2 system call to redirect output of one file handler to another.

For e.g. in your case to make all std::cout write to the log file used by glog just do

dup2(glog_file_handler,stdout);

This would work if you can some how get filehandle of the log file that glog is writing to. Refer http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html for more details.

Hope this helps.

P.S. This won't work if your program has multiple threads/procesess writing to same glog file and if glog does synchronized writes to log file

Comment: Thanks @A.N. glog writes asynchronously; but I'm struggling to find the file handler in the google library! I'll investigate further.